# How to float an image to a certain spot inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image on a certain spot on a div. [Here is what it looks like so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKII0.png) The boxed area is where I wish to display the image (which is circled).

I tired mutliple ways yet the image only seems to

1. Remain on the left
2. Move to the right but goes under the text

What I'm trying to achieve is to place the image on top of the listed text so it can fill in the empty area. Also, I am trying to make sure that the scrollbar *doesn't* appear.

Any help is much appreciated!

css

```
body {
   font-size: 12px;
   background-color: #f1f6f9;
   color: #7e7e7e;
   background-image: url("none.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
}

* {
   cursor: url('cursor.png'), auto;
}

.box {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
   border-color: #000;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding: 15px 22px 15px 22px;
   height: 250px;
   width: 265px;
   font-family: 'mplus 1p', sans-serif;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.links {
   text-align: center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
   border-color: #000;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: none;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 15px;
   width: 289px;
   font-family: 'mplus 1p', sans-serif;
}

.icon {
   width: auto;
   height: 85px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 12px;
}

li {
   list-style-image: url('bullet1.gif');
   list-style-position: inside;
   margin-left: 1em;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 5px;
   height: auto;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #ffc9e5;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-right: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background: #d6ffee;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: transparent;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box">
 <center><img class="icon" src="icon1.png"></center>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li><a href="personality.html">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="more.html">text</a></li>
  <img src="bunny1.gif" style="float: right">
  </div>
  <div class="links">
  text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `img` to be above the elements you want floated beside of it. So just move the `img` before the list. And if you want to move it down on the page, use `margin` or `transform: translateY()`.

But your `li`' also need to be in a `ul`, and the `center` tag is deprecated - you need to use CSS for that instead.

```css
body {
   font-size: 12px;
   background-color: #f1f6f9;
   color: #7e7e7e;
   background-image: url("none.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
}

* {
   cursor: url('cursor.png'), auto;
}

.box {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
   border-color: #000;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding: 15px 22px 15px 22px;
   height: 250px;
   width: 265px;
   font-family: 'mplus 1p', sans-serif;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.links {
   text-align: center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
   border-color: #000;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: none;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 15px;
   width: 289px;
   font-family: 'mplus 1p', sans-serif;
}

.icon {
   width: auto;
   height: 85px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 12px;
}

li {
   list-style-image: url('bullet1.gif');
   list-style-position: inside;
   margin-left: 1em;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 5px;
   height: auto;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #ffc9e5;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-right: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background: #d6ffee;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: transparent;
}

ul {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="center"><img class="icon" src="icon1.png"></div>
  <img src="bunny1.gif" style="float: right; margin-top: 2em;">

  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li><a href="personality.html">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="more.html">text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="links">
  text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px"> text <img src="bullet2.png" style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px">  text
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! My only concern is that it seems to make the space between the upper image and the `ul` bigger as shown [here](https://tomoya.neocities.org/show.html).

Comment: @Ren you're welcome. looks like you need to add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the `ul` (like my code above).